# Crystal Reports: New Page

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

My application prints statements for customers. Naturally, I want each customer's statement to start at the top of a page. How do I make it do that?

In the Section Expert, if I check 'new page before' the first group, it wastes a page at the beginning, and if I check 'new page after' the last group, it wastes a page at the end. I don't mind so much when printing 350 statements, but when I print just one, it's pretty low class as well as wasteful.

This is the 'built in' Crystal Reports in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this on new page after

Not(OnLastRecord)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 'keeptogether' set? You should be able to do 'new page after' on the group footer and it will only go to the next page if there is a following group. Otherwise it will print the page and report footer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a formula for the 'new page before' option. Something like the below would return true for pages 2+ of course, giving you the new page when needed. Just a theory. :)

```
PageNumber > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write down the two lines of codes and it will work properly--

rDoc.ReportDefinition.Sections["GroupHeaderSection1"].SectionFormat.EnableNewPageBefore = true;
                        rDoc.ReportDefinition.Sections["GroupHeaderSection1"].SectionFormat.EnableKeepTogether = true;

Thanks and Regards